# Checking if a table contains a Row C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to figure out if my data table contains a certain row. So I used the .Contains method, but when I tried to run my program I was met with a MissingPrimaryKeyException which I can't figure out.

```
DataTable table = dataQuery.executeQuery();

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    if(table.Rows.Contains("certainRow"))
    {
        blah blah blah
    ...
```

I am only getting the exception the 2nd time I call table.Rows which is what is making no sense to me. If my table didn't have a primary key, wouldn't it have given me an error in the foreach call?

EDIT: I just realized that Contains did something else than I thought it did. Matthijs... yes that is kind of what I want. I need to know if "certainRow" is actually a row that exists otherwise I cannot manipulate the data in that row.

Unfortunately I am new to C# and haven't programmed in anything in over 5years so I cannot figure out if there is a method that does what I want. Or if I need to create something myself.

EDIT#2:
I figured out a solution to my problem using the DataTableReader.

```
private bool doesExist(string rowName, DataTable table)
    {
        bool value = false;
        DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(table);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (reader.GetValue(i) == rowName)
                {
                    value = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic. You are iterating through all rows, but still calling the whole `table.Rows`... Shouldn't that be something like `if(row.Contains("certainRow")`?

Comment: Can you debug and visualize the data table? check that all rows had a value in the pk col?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `DataTableReader`, more information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

An example, would be:

```
private static DataTable GetCustomer()
{
     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     DataColumn id = table.Columns.Add(@"Id", typeof(int));

     table.Columns.Add(@"Name", typeof(string));
     table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { id };
     table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, @"John" });
     return table;
}
```

The above code will build a table, as you see you define your `Primary Key` and add the Content.  That is how you would *build* the table.  Now to read, you would:

```
using(DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(new DataTable[] { customer }))
{
     do
     {
         if(reader.HasRows)
         {
              // Do Something
         }
     } while (reader.NextResult());
}
```

As you can see it validates the row exist, then performs a task.  Very simple example, hope it helps.

The `.Contains` will return a `boolean` for a true or false value.

In regards to your comment, you can call `reader[@"ColumnName"]` and it should attempt to read it without an issue.  So if:

```
if(reader[@"ColumnName"] != DBNull.Value)
{
     // Do Something.
}
```

Comment: The table is being generated automatically using an SQL query. The problem is that some of the early databases do not contain the same rows/columns as the newer databases. So I want to put in a check to make sure that I am not trying to manipulate a row that doesn't exist.

Comment: Modified lower portion of answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, your comment on he DataReader ultimately lead me to a solution... though I did end up making my own method. Maybe I am still missing something that has already been created.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write:

```
bool contains = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().SelectMany(r => r.ItemArray).Contains(value);
```